# getting "invalid multibyte escape: /^\xFF\xFE/ (SyntaxError)" error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, encoding, syntax-error, multibyte

I'm using the VPIM gem for rails to create vcards for users based on their profile information.

It all works fine on my local host, but when I deploy to Heroku, the app crashes.

I'm getting the error below in the heroku logs, which I assume is what is causing the app to crash...

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vpim-0.695/lib/vpim/vcard.rb:678: invalid multibyte escape: /^\xFE\xFF/ (SyntaxError)
2013-10-27T15:52:14.211497+00:00 app[web.1]: invalid multibyte escape: /^\xFF\xFE/
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Here's the gem I'm using and some possible solutions that I haven't been able to get working yet. It might be because of my level of understanding of ruby-on-rails.

Gem: github(dot)com/fraser/vpim-rails

Possible solutions:
https://github.com/sam-github/vpim/issues/5

https://github.com/GetJobber/vpim-rails/commit/0c92b5d7f9b2f6a59bdeea3127dbb668072371cc

Any help will be much appreciated.

-Ethan

Comment: It seems like it's not compatible with Ruby 2.0. Have you tried one of the forks that supports it?

Comment: @Beerlington I installed the Vcard fork which supposedly supports it. But there isn't any documentation on how to go about integrating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a quick fix for it. Open the following file
**"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/vpim-0.695/lib/vpim/vcard.rb"**

in text editor, and add the following line at the beginning of file.
**"# encoding: ISO-8859-1"**

This solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was getting the same error trying to migrate plugins with Redmine 2.5.2. Setting the encoding for `vpim` sorted it for me as well.